# How would I read this array ("stdClass Object")

Tags: php, arrays, json, variables, decode

I am using the Quizlet API 2.0, and I am pretty new to this

How do I read a value(s) from something like this:

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 102269 [name] => Learn Spanish with Cats! [set_count] => 3 [user_count] => 10 [created_date] => 1308035691 [is_public] => 1 [has_password] => [has_access] => 1 [has_discussion] => 1 [member_add_sets] => 1 [description] => This set is exclusively for Spanish flashcard sets with relevant cat images as the set definitions. [sets] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 6081999 [url] => http://quizlet.com/6081999/lesson-4-with-catsdogs-flash-cards/ [title] => Lesson 4 (with cats+dogs) [created_by] => wsvincent [term_count] => 33 [created_date] => 1311984796 [modified_date] => 1312490710 [has_images] => 1 [subjects] => Array ( [0] => spanish cats dogs ) [visibility] => public [editable] => groups [has_access] => 1 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 5855751 [url] => http://quizlet.com/5855751/paso-a-paso-book-1-chapter-4-flash-cards/ [title] => Paso a Paso Book 1 Chapter 4 [created_by] => catdawg426 [term_count] => 30 [created_date] => 1307761267 [modified_date] => 1307819129 [has_images] => 1 [subjects] => Array ( [0] => spanish ) [visibility] => public [editable] => only_me [has_access] => 1 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 5873819 [url] => http://quizlet.com/5873819/los-gatos-de-viaje-flash-cards/ [title] => Los Gatos de Viaje! [created_by] => tiffreja [term_count] => 21 [created_date] => 1307996657 [modified_date] => 1307996796 [has_images] => 1 [subjects] => Array ( [0] => spanish [1] => language [2] => foreign ) [visibility] => public [editable] => only_me [has_access] => 1 ) ) [members] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [username] => philfreo [role] => creator [email_notification] => 1 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [username] => milkncookies [role] => member [email_notification] => 1 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [username] => Icypaw [role] => member [email_notification] => ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [username] => luckycat10 [role] => member [email_notification] => ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [username] => jeffchan [role] => member [email_notification] => ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [username] => catchdave [role] => member [email_notification] => 1 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [username] => tiffreja [role] => member [email_notification] => 1 ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [username] => catdawg426 [role] => member [email_notification] => 1 ) [8] => stdClass Object ( [username] => ihaque [role] => member [email_notification] => 1 ) [9] => stdClass Object ( [username] => jalenack [role] => member [email_notification] => 1 ) ) )
```

For instance, if I want to get the name of that first set, "Learn Spanish with Cats", how do I echo it via variable?

It already converts the JSON to an array I think:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
```

Comment: When you paste a dump like that, please make sure you include the line breaks.

Comment: `json_decode()` with one argument does not convert the JSON to an array. See http://php.net/json_decode

Comment: If you add second argument `json_decode($json,true);`  When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your object is not an array, but rather, well, an Object. So use the `->` operator to access its properties:

```
echo $data->name;
```

It contains a property which itself is an array of additional objects. For example, to get the URL of id 6081999, you would do:

```
echo $data->sets[0]->url;
// http://quizlet.com/6081999/lesson-4-with-catsdogs-flash-cards/
```

Comment: What if there were multiple sets with "name" as the identifier? Would it be `$data->name[1]`?

Comment: @GrayAdams I just addressed a similar issue in an edit. For the sets, which are an array, you use the `[]` array index, followed by the desired object property via `->`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple solution to convert a **stdClass Object** in array in php with `get_object_vars`

Look at : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

Example :

```
dump($array);
$var = get_object_vars($array);
dump($var);
```

Or replace `dump()` function by `print_r()`

Answer (score 1):

Use function key

```
eg echo key($array)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have looked something before, when you use the json_decode()

```
$data = json_decode();
```

U can send some parameters, the first of them is "$json", it will be the json string

```
{"1":"first","2":"second"}
```

But that json decode with one parameter return an Object and the default value of the second parameter is "false". If you want that back in array you only need to use the second parameter and send "true".

```
$data =json_decode($json,true);
```

And you can recibe it like an array. :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you got stdClass Object in the array, for example
`$user = $result1->fetch_object()` then set `$user` into a variable
 **`$val = $user->user_id` (make sure user_id is your database column name, its the column name)**. You will get a single value in $val that comes from database.